# Validation error while inserting Data to sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am new in asp.net development.
I am trying to make a webpage using asp.net and SQL server 2008.
Just a simple page through which data will be inserted to the database. But I noticed it is taking duplicate records as well. So I used "Unique" constraint while the respective table and it is working fine.
But I wanted to show an error message which says "DATA already exists" after I am clicking the Insert button on the page.
Is it possible to check for duplicate entries and show the error while we are inserting data to a database?
without java-script or ajax please.
Please help with a code snippet.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Hey welcome to SO! A couple tips to get a more useful response: Tell us what you've done so far (did an okay job here), show us what you've done so far (source code, source code, source code!), and then explain in a detailed manner where exactly you are having a problem and what you need help with. "Code broke please help!" type of posts usually don't get much traction

Comment: HI DCruz22, 
I have created a stored procedure to insert the data into the respective table. For testing purpose I am using only one column and trying to apply the validation to that column.

Comment: Sounds like you need some client side form validation.  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-helpers-forms-and-validation

Comment: Hey @Pseudonym ,
Thank you for replying.
Still trying with the code. I have a simple insert query and it is working fine. I am sorry that i am not able post the codes but this is exactly what I have done so far.
I have no idea about MVC or JavaScript so I was thinking of adding validation control about the duplicate entries.

Comment: Hey @DCruz22 
I have created a stored procedure to insert the data into the respective table. For testing purpose I am using only one column and trying to apply the validation to that column. Also came up with a simple insert query.